# How to get info of a collection with space character in its name?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I use MongoDB for a Node project. I created a collection "Births and deaths" with mongoose. When I open mongodb and I write *db.Births and deaths.find()*, it returns error. What's wrong?

Comment: Ideally, you shouldn't create names with spaces in DB -> good practises
If needed you can assign them to a variable 
`var collection = db.getCollection("Births and deaths"); collection.find()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
db.getCollection("Births and deaths").find()
```

But do not create collection name like this. Please follow recommended best practices.